# Is there a proof of the equivalence between Cronbach's alpha and reliability calculation from a CFA?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, structural-equation-modeling, reliability, cronbachs-alpha, mcdonalds-omega

Given a uni-dimensional CFA, reliability can be calculated as:

$$
\omega = {\left(\sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_i\right)^2\over \left(\sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_i\right)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^p\sigma^2_i}
$$
where $\lambda_i$ is the factor loading of item $i$ and $\sigma^2_i$ is the measurement error/unique variance of item $i$.

It can be shown that $\omega$ is equivalent to Cronbach's alpha if all loadings are constrained to be equal and all unique variances are constrained to be equal.

I understand Cronbach's alpha assumes tau-equivalence, but the sample covariance matrix that supports the calculation of alpha isn't subjected to any constraints while the calculation from CFA parameters depends on imposed constraints. Why then does this equivalence exist? Is there a mathematical proof for the equivalence? I've had suspicions that this somehow related to matrix rotations, but my linear algebra knowledge is lacking.

Answer (score 0):

Really what one should do when calculating Cronbach's alpha is use the tau-equivalence model-implied variances and model-implied covariances of the observed variables (which ARE subject to constraints, namely the rather strict constraint of a single factor model with equal loadings). The fact that alpha can be calculated based on sample variances/covariances without estimating and testing the model of tau equivalence does not mean that this the right thing to do. This contributes to a lot of confusion about alpha because it is often (incorrectly) applied to multidimensional non-tau-equivalent measures (but this is not obvious since no CFA model is being tested).

The two estimates (sample vs. model-implied alpha) will likely not be equivalent because the tau-equivalence model-implied variances and covariances will likely deviate (at least somewhat) from the observed (sample) variances and covariances due to sampling error, even when the model of tau equivalence is correct for the data (i.e., is the data-generating model).

Comment: Even with as few as n=20, the sample and model-implied alpha are very similar, only occasionally differing in the fifth+ decimal. But this still begs the question why the sample and model-implied alpha are asymptotically equal.